# ArchUnit class link in violation messages

Tags: java, archunit

I've noticed that using standard ArchConditions display messages in the following format:

```
Class <full_class_path> does not <some_rule> in (<class_link>)
```

However, this is not the case for custom conditions that add violation messages to the event like:

```
events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(item, item.getName() + " some message"));
```

With this, no link to the violating class is appended to the message automatically. I wonder what the first argument (correspondingObject) is actually used for then.

Is this a bug in the framework or am I missing something? Having these links are really useful. I've tried using the JavaDoc @link notation in the message string to no avail.

Comment: I also think that the library itself does not use a `ConditionEvent`'s `correspondingObject` but just offers it to clients implementing their own `ConditionEvent.Handler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the domain classes like JavaClass, JavaMember or JavaAccess implement the interface `HasSourceCodeLocation`, which contains the method `getSourceCodeLocation` to obtain the location in the source code. The returned object `SourceCodeLocation` can then be used to output the location via the `toString` method.

For example

```java
events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(item, item.getDescription() + " is violated in " + item.getSourceCodeLocation()));
```

would return

```
Class <org.example.Dummy> is violated in (Dummy.java:0)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this will help immensely!

Comment: Since `v1.0.0-rc1`, you can also use [`com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ConditionEvent#createMessage`](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/commit/a3268fb0bcabc9535c7c280270f2d039c8feadf9).